# Display the output of a function in a tkinter label widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been reading a lot of stack overflow lately, and I 'd like to thank everyone who's active here for their contributions. This community has helped me a lot in my learning python!

I am trying to put together a pretty simple name generator program, in which every time you press a button in the tkinter GUI a new name is generated into a label widget.

The generator works with the random module picking words from pre-compiled lists and putting them together in  combinations, the structures of which are defined in the function 'generate_name'.

I've gotten the program to work fine in console, but I can't figure out how to get it to work with tkinter.

I'm hoping to build a tkinter GUI where you press a button and the output of the 'generate_name' will be displayed on a tkinter label. However, I can't seem to achieve this, and I can only get the output of the function to be displayed in the console.

I've read many posts related to similar problems but I just can't seem to get my head around this. I've tried many alternative approaches to this, and although I have been able to get the outputs of simpler functions to be displayed, e.g. ones where you do simple math equations with variables, I simply can't get the randomly generated name to appear anywhere but the console.

Hopefully I've been able to articulate my problem clearly.

Here is a simplified version of the code I'm working on:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

#Lists of words that will be used by the generate_name() function

wordclass1 = (
'word1',
'word2',
'word3',
)

wordclass2 = (
'word4',
'word5',
'word6',
)

wordclass3 = (
'word7',
'word8',
'word9',
)

#These functions do the actual random generation of the names.

def name1():
    full_name = random.choice(wordclass1) + " " + random.choice(wordclass2)
    print(full_name)

def name2():
    full_name = random.choice(wordclass2) + " " + random.choice(wordclass3)
    print(full_name)

def name3():
    full_name = random.choice(wordclass1) + " " + random.choice(wordclass2) + " " + random.choice(wordclass3)
    print(full_name)

#This function randomly picks the individual name that should be displayed on the tkinter label

def generate_name():
    list = (name1, name2, name3)
    return(random.choice(list)())
    name = random.choice(list)

#This function is supposed to display the text on the tkinter label

def write():
    label = Label(root, text=(generate_name()))
    label.pack()

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="Generate a name!", command=write)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance!

I am still very much a beginner and I'm sure there's a bunch of things wrong with my code but any advice would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to initially create and empty `Label` and then put something new into it whenever the `Button`'s clicked (using the universal widget method named [`config()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html)). I also changed how some of your other functions worked, notably `generate_name()` to get everything working properly — I think most of the changes will be obvious.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

#Lists of words that will be used by the generate_name() function

wordclass1 = (
'word1',
'word2',
'word3',
)

wordclass2 = (
'word4',
'word5',
'word6',
)

wordclass3 = (
'word7',
'word8',
'word9',
)

#These functions do the actual random generation of the names.

def name1():
    full_name = random.choice(wordclass1) + " " + random.choice(wordclass2)
    return full_name

def name2():
    full_name = random.choice(wordclass2) + " " + random.choice(wordclass3)
    return full_name

def name3():
    full_name = random.choice(wordclass1) + " " + random.choice(wordclass2) + " " + random.choice(wordclass3)
    return full_name

#This function randomly picks the individual name that should be displayed on the tkinter label

def generate_name():
    return random.choice([name1, name2, name3])()

#This function is supposed to display the text on the tkinter label

def write():
    label.config(text=generate_name())

root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text='')
label.pack()
button = Button(root, text="Generate a name!", command=write)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `random.choice([name1, name2, name3])()` uses less memory.

Comment: @acw1668: A valid — albeit minor point. Its computational efficiency more so, IMO.